# How to imitate Python like dictionaries in C++ using STL?

Tags: python, c++11

I have a data structure which looks like this. It's more like a dictionary in python and it stores information like this.

```
D={0:{'x':2,'y':5},1:{'x':4,'y':5}}
```

This represents two keys 0 and 1, each having x and y coordinates. In Python I can easily initialize like this.

But how can I do it in C++? I have used the following declaration.

```
map<int, map<char, float>> D;
```

But after this I am unable to proceed. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested initializer lists. The syntax is slightly different to python's, but it is clear what is going on:

```
map<int, map<char, float>> D0{{0, {{'x', 2}, {'y', 5}}},
                              {1, {{'x', 4}, {'y', 5}}}};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use an initializer list:

```
map<int, map<char, float>> D = {{0,{{'x',2},{'y',5}}},{1,{{'x',4},{'y',5}}}};
```

Basically, you put a pair of braces around each pair of values to initialize pairs, and a pair of braces around each list of key/value pairs to initialize maps:

```
map<int, map<char, float>> D =
  { //begin map initialisation
    { //begin key/value pair defining the first element
      0, //key of the first element
      { // begin map (value of the first element)
        {'x',2}, // initialiser for key/value pair 'x',2
        {'y',5}  // initialiser for key/value pair 'y',5
      } // end of value of the first element
    }, //end of key/value pair for the first element
    {1,{{'x',4},{'y',5}}} // similar stuff for second element of the map
  }; //end of the map
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I can think of with C++11's `initializer_list`

```
map<int, map<char, float>> D = {
    {0, {{'x', 2}, {'y', 5}}},
    {1, {{'x', 4}, {'y', 5}}}
};
```